# Express res.json not as expected

Tags: express

I wrote like this:

```
var strange = []
strange.push({
    xixix: 'xixixi'
})
res.json({
    success: true,
    result: strange,
    tt: Array.prototype.concat.apply([], strange),
    kk: [ { 'xix': 'xixix'}]
})
```

However, the data type showed in browser:

[image]

Why tt and kk is not an array tyoe but a object?

Comment: What's the point of `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], strange)` instead of just using `strange` there.  Also, I don't think ``Array.prototype.concat.apply([], strange)`` is correct.  That's like doing `[].concat(strange[0])` and `strange[0]` is not an array which is what `.concat()` is expecting.

Comment: just a test,  the key point is why kk is an object instead of array

Comment: Not sure why it shows that way, but an array is an object.

Comment: raw string in chrome shows normal:{"success":true,"result":[{"xixix":"xixixi"}],"tt":[{"xixix":"xixixi"}],"kk":[{"xix":"xixix"}]}   how come turns out a object....

Comment: So, the JSON is just fine.  What you're asking about then is just what the console is showing?  Did you try `Array.isArray()` on it?

Comment: no, the raw string is array, why it shows as an object,  not an array

Comment: Did you expand it in the console to see what it actually is.  Consoles all have their own way of displaying things that is completely non-standard.  It doesn't sound like you've found anything other than work in the console that isn't what you expect.  If the data is an array with `Array.isArray()`, then chalk it up to a console oddity.

Comment: Looks just like what I could expect in Chrome here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aeuk1s7q/1/

Comment: Are you looking at the node.js debugger, running in Chrome?   If so, I think that's just how it displays things.